# How to fix FOSUserBundle submitting?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I tried to overwrite templates but I can't submit the form. When I click the submit button the data will be saved to the URL. When I delete my templates and use the default everything works. I didn't override RegistrationController.

Symfony v4.3.4

My register_content.html.twig

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

<section class="sign-in">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6 offset-sm-1 offset-md-2 offset-lg-3 top-negative">
                <h1 class="text-center">{{ 'registration.title'|trans }}</h1>
                <form class="sign-in-form mt-74">
                    <div class="row">
                        {{ form_start(form, {'method': 'POST', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register')}) }}
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mb-20">
                                {{ form_widget(form.email, {'label': false,'attr': {'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'registration.email_reg'|trans}}) }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mb-20">
                                {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, {'label': false,'attr': {'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'registration.password'|trans}}) }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mb-20">
                                {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, {'label': false,'attr': {'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'registration.repeat_password'|trans}}) }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mb-20">
                                {{ form_widget(form.firstname, {'label': false,'attr': {'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'registration.first_name'|trans}}) }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mb-20">
                                {{ form_widget(form.lastname, {'label': false,'attr': {'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'registration.last_name'|trans}}) }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mb-20">
                                {{ form_widget(form.tel, {'label': false,'attr': {'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'registration.tel'|trans }}) }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                                {{ form_widget(form.submit, {'attr': {'class': 'button button-dark'}}) }}
                            </div>
                        {{ form_end(form) }}
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My layout.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}
    {% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 form-opening tags. `<form class="sign-in-form mt-74">` and the one created with `{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'POST', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register')}) }}` (likewise two form tags closing).

You an add your `class="sign-in-form mt-74"` in the form_start tag

... {'method': 'post',  'action': path('....'), **'attr': {'class': 'sign-in-form mt-74'** }} ...